# Using :: everytime in C++

Tags: c++, game-engine

Alright, so I am totally new in C++ since I come from C and Java, so a simple question. I have the following header called *Engine.h* (the code is from a [tutorial to make games with C++](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7lh9ryRNHSJjzOD070wCctd3PvC0h4uG)):

```
#ifndef TWITCH_ENGINE
#define TWITCH_ENGINE

#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")

class Engine
{
public:
    static int SCREEN_WIDTH;
    static int SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    Engine();
    ~Engine();

    bool initialize(char *windowTitle);

private:

};

#endif
```

and the source file *Engine.cpp*

```
#include "Engine.h"

int Engine::SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024;
int Engine::SCREEN_HEIGHT = 768;

Engine::Engine() {


}

Engine::~Engine() {


}

bool Engine::initialize(char* windowTitle);
```

So the question is, do I have to write every time Engine::*member_name* or is there a way to avoid this, maybe by writing something like `using namespace Engine;`? And if so, what are the beneficts of coding that way?

Comment: You have to write it every time for out-of-line method definitions like this.

Comment: Benefits? How would the compiler know what `initialize` method you are defining without you explicitly telling the compiler that you are defining `Engine::initialize(char *)` method?

Comment: It might seem like a lot of pointless typing but you get used to it and soon come to expect it.

Comment: You can always define the functions inline, within the class definitions.   That has disadvantages - such as, if it is necessary to change the definition of ANY member function at all, then EVERY compilation unit that uses the class must be re-built.   In large projects, with classes used in many places, that can increase incremental build times by orders of magnitude (e.g. from minutes to days).  Conversely, an advantage of defining member functions out of line as you are, is that such complete rebuilds are not required for incremental/minor changes.

Comment: @AnT I thought that the compiler would know just because the .cpp file have the same name as the header file

Comment: @Martín: Firstly, compiler never takes into account file names. File names don't matter at all. Secondly, by the time it actually begins *compiling* the code, header files are no longer in the picture. Thirdly, nothing prevents you from defining multiple different classes, all with `initialize` method, in the same pair of header and `.cpp` files.

Comment: @Martín .cpp file can have different name than its header file

Comment: This is why *programmers* invented *code completion*.

Comment: Just a heads up, the double colon `::` in C++ is also called the [scope resolution operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-operator-in-c/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you have to.

Long answer: `using namespace` only works with namespaces. No surprise here. A class is not a namespace. If you move the code to the header, this necessity falls away, but that has other downsides that are the same as in C, so you probably know them.

Comment: Taking the question literally then technically the answer is no. Macros.